# Convert .class files to binary code (1's and 0's)

Tags: java, binary, machine-code

So say I have several .class files that make up some java program. I want to take these .class files and convert the java code to its binary equivalent (long string  of 1's and 0's). Are there any online converters that will take the .class files and convert them to their binary equivalent?

Comment: Is "binary equivalent" meant to be a text file of 0s and 1s? Or what do you imagine / try to achieve?

Comment: How is a binary dump of a file useful to you? Any why do you think this is java-specific? The method to obtain a binary dump of any type of file will be the same - whether it's a .class file, an executable of an image file.

Comment: Why?  That question aside, in the highly likely event there isn't  a ready-made solution out there, it wouldn't be too difficult to write such a program.

Comment: @zapl yes, a text file of 0s and 1s. I want to take the binary list, take every 4 numbers and convert it to a hex value. This hex value can be converted to a color. I can then plot pixels on a graph where each pixel is a hex value from the binary list. Almost like a "picture" or signature of the program. I thought it would be a neat concept.

Comment: @KevinAnderson The above comment shows why. Just a project I thought would look cool. As to solutions, I've looked online and most of my searches resulted in turning .class files to .exe which is not what I want.

Comment: Why would you go through the steps of first converting the whole file into binary character outputs (making the file 8 times as big), then to hex (making it 4 times smaller), and then to a color, when you can write a Java program that converts any file to a colored image in one pass? And why does it have to be an online converter? In that case you're asking for an external resource, which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Above comments show why. I don't think it's java specific, I program with java so I require java specific solutions/answers.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt My experiences with Java are not that advanced where I can write a program to convert a file to a colored image. It doesn't have to be an online converter. I imagined that there is a simple solution so I figured there would be an online converter already.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around in some DOS related forums, people recommended Hex Editor Neo which takes a file and shows the hex equivalent. This skips the need to convert to binary then to hex.